# How do I invert the exit code of a program or pipe within ZSH?

Tags: zsh, exit-code

I want to invert the exit code of a piped command sequence: `foo | bar` within the ZSH. So `0` maps to `1` and `1-128` maps to `0`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

POSIX shells, including *bash*, *zsh* and *dash*, support the **[`!`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_02)** modifier:

```
! foo | bar
```